# Do I have to call SHA1_Final() if I abandon hash calculation?

Tags: c++, openssl, sha1

It is regarding all SHA family.

I look at the https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/SHA1.html page and I don't see anything that would prevent me from NOT calling `SHA1_Final()` in case I want to abandon hash calculation.

In other words, is it okay if I do:

```
try {
    SHA1_Init(&ctx);
    while (!finish) {
        const Data& data = getData();
        SHA1_Update(&ctx, data.data(), data.len());
    }
    SHA1_Final(&md, &ctx);
}
catch(const std::exception& e) {
    std::cerr << "Ooops, exception while reading data. " << e.what() << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "Not calling SHA1_Final!" << std::endl;
    throw;
}
```

My guts are telling me that I should be okay with not calling `SHA1_Final()`, and that if there was a need to 'clean up' ctx, there should be `SHA1_Destroy()`, which, of course is absent...

Comment: My guts say the same. There is a `SHA_CTX` context. If you discard it at the end of the method, then there is no problem. Not sure if you can reuse a `SHA1_CTX` if you don't `SHA1_Final`.

Comment: I can't find the code for `SHA1_Final`... [Still the code for `SHA512_Final`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/4bed94f0c11ef63587c6b2edb03c3c438e221604/crypto/sha/sha512.c#L140), that should be similar enough, doesnt clean/free anything.

Comment: @xanatos - I am only concerned that this does reverse engineering, and depends on implementation, which in future can change. `SHA1_CTX` can be reused if one calls `SHA1_Init()` on it. Thank you for your efforts!

Comment: @gregorz The documentation doesn't speak about the necessity of using `_Final`, a similar implementation doesn't need it, and it would be against the logic of the context as the container of the temporary data to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many `SHA_*` methods are defined [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_0/crypto/include/internal/md32_common.h), that is a file that through the preprocessor is "configured" to be the methods for SHA1, SHA256...

The [`HASH_FINAL`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_0/crypto/include/internal/md32_common.h#L316) method is the `SHA1_Final` (and `SHA256_Final`). In here the only operation that "smells" of cleaning is an

```
OPENSSL_cleanse(p, HASH_CBLOCK);
```

where `OPENSSL_cleanse` is

> OPENSSL_cleanse() fills ptr of size len with a string of 0's

(taken from [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/OPENSSL_cleanse.html)).

But the size of the `OPENSSL_cleanse` is `HASH_CBLOCK`, so I'll say that it is cleaning the internal buffer used for keeping partial pieces of source data that have to be hashed. Explanation: SHA1 works on 512 bits (64 bytes) of data at a time. If you try to hash 70 bytes of data with a `SHA1_Update`, 64 bytes are hashed and 6 bytes are saved somewhere for the next `SHA1_Update`. The `SHA1_Final` finishes using these bytes and then clears them.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you for looking this up. I suspect that OpenSSL knows what they do :)

Comment: @Grzegorz Note that doing what you are doing is potentially keeping a piece of source data in memory. For example a password is normally shorter than 64 bytes, so it would be kept in the context waiting for the `_Final`. If the data is a super-secret and should stay in memory for the shortest time possible to mitigate some server attacks, then you are creating a vulnerability. Note even that `SHA1_Init` as the first instruction does `memset(c, 0, sizeof(*c));`, so it zeroes (in a non-secure way) the context, cleaning this state.